# LibreOffice has some black on black UI components, making them unreadable (since upgrade to 21.10)

Tags: themes, libreoffice, 21.10

Since I upgraded to Ubuntu 21.10, some UI parts are displayed with black text on black background in LibreOffice 7.2.1.2, making them unreadable.

This is the case in particular for sheet names in Calc:

[image: Unreadable sheet name]

I can't find a way to fix it...

Comment: if you right click on the tab, can you change the tab colour?

Comment: Nope... changing the tab color will underline it with the color, but it stays black on black...

Comment: bizarre... my instance on MATE 21.10 (upgraded from 21.04) same version of LO does not show this issue.

Comment: Looking further at your graphic there is a plus sign to the left of the black tab - this does not appear to be the case with v7n which displays a new sheet icon - are you sure you have the correct version details? Further, you have tagged `themes` but if you go to `Tools > Options > Personalisation` have you set other than `Default look, do not use Themes`?

Comment: I have "Default look, do not use Themes". But I found the issue to be related to my gnome theme (Materia compact). Switching to other themes solves the issue...

Answer (score 4, accepted):

THe problem is due to the Materia-compact Gnome Theme used:

see https://github.com/nana-4/materia-theme/issues/560

Workarounds are:

1. use another theme alltogether
2. use another theme for LibreOffice only:

   ```
   GTK_THEME="Adwaita"    
   find /usr/share/applications -name libreoffice* | xargs -i cp {} ~/.local/share/applications    
   find ~/.local/share/applications -name libreoffice* | xargs sed -i "s/Exec=/Exec=env GTK_THEME=$GTK_THEME /g"
   ```

Now, LibreOffice uses adwaita theme (but the window title bar still uses materia-compact, so it does not feel weird).